# ImageMagick won't convert .png to .jpg

Tags: linux, imagemagick, png, jpeg

So I want to convert a bunch of images (a lot of them, it's from a dataset) from .png to .jpg, and it is recommended to use imagemagick (along with 'parallel', but the problem lies with imagemagick for now).
The conversion is not done properly, I have tried

```
magick example.png example.jpg
```

and

```
convert example.png example.jpg
```

but it seems that imagemagick just renames the file, as the resulting image is titled "example.jpg", but using

```
identify -verbose example.jpg
```

reveals that the image is a .png file. Indeed when I manually rename the file to "example.png", the image loads just fine.

Has anyone encountered this problem, and has found a solution? I don't necessarily want to use imagemagick, any tool that can batch convert a large number of images at a reasonable time frame would also be great.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It seems unlikely that **ImageMagick** would create a PNG file when you asked for a JPEG. If you want to convert a PNG to a JPEG, please try the following procedure:

```
# Remove anything likely to confuse
rm result.jpg 2> /dev/null

# Convert PNG to JPEG
magick input.png result.jpg

# Check result using 'file' command
file input.png result.jpg

input.png:  PNG image data, 70 x 46, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
result.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, aspect ratio, density 1x1, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 70x46, components 3

# Check result (in hex)
xxd result.jpg | head -4

00000000: ffd8 ffe0 0010 4a46 4946 0001 0100 0001  ......JFIF......
00000010: 0001 0000 ffdb 0043 0003 0202 0202 0203  .......C........
00000020: 0202 0203 0303 0304 0604 0404 0404 0806  ................
00000030: 0605 0609 080a 0a09 0809 090a 0c0f 0c0a  ................
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for the delay I've been busy. I tried it but when I run the 'file' command, I get: "0000000000.png: PNG image data, 1242 x 375, 8-bit grayscale, non-interlaced" and
"0000000000.jpg: PNG image data, 1242 x 375, 8-bit grayscale, non-interlaced" (the name of the file is the zeros).

Comment: I'll try reinstalling imagemagick, maybe even an older version, maybe it's a bug